# Thermostat replacement, no c wire

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, nest

I have an almost 20 year old Taco thermostat that I am trying to replace with a Nest thermostat for a forced hot water heating system.

The Nest requires a W, R, and common wire, current only uses W and R. The wiring coming into the wall for the thermostat has four wires but the g and y are cut down.  I see that you can use one of these as the common but- the wiring on the burner end is not straightforward as I have seen in other setups.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram on your furnace/boiler please?

Comment: A pic showing how these wires are terminated on the furnace control board and at the existing thermostat would be helpful. As it is, it's just a jumbled mess of wires that could go anywhere.

Comment: Only diagram I could find so far is on page 10 of this manual: https://www.laars.com/images/uploads/products/1100C.pdf

Comment: I will take more pics tonight

Comment: @Sarah -- can you step back and get us an overall shot of what's going on? Also, can you find your aquastat...?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a volt meter, buy one.  $15 or even $10 if you want a really cheap one.

1. Measure voltage between these two terminals.

[image]

Should be 24V.  If not, stop.

2. Connect the unused blue wire to the indicated terminal (along with the white wire already there) or to anywhere directly connected to that.
3. Go to the thermostat, measure between the R wire and the blue one you used. Should be 24V.  If not, stop.
4. If all good so far, blue is your C wire.